# Starting httpd centos in ssl mode doesn't work

Tags: apache, ssl, https, centos

In my server I'm logged as root. I configured the web server of centos (httpd) to use https. If I start the server so-as-is it works, but if I change the SSL port it fails. If I run this command

```
systemctl status httpd.service
```

it give me the following log:

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ven 2016-05-27 22:50:25 CEST; 10s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 1776 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1774 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1774 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

mag 27 22:50:25 vps1 httpd[1774]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8891
mag 27 22:50:25 vps1 httpd[1774]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8891
mag 27 22:50:25 vps1 httpd[1774]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
mag 27 22:50:25 vps1 httpd[1774]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
mag 27 22:50:25 vps1 systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mag 27 22:50:25 vps1 kill[1776]: kill: cannot find process ""
mag 27 22:50:25 vps1 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
mag 27 22:50:25 vps1 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
mag 27 22:50:25 vps1 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
mag 27 22:50:25 vps1 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

I can't understand the problem. With 443 works, with 8891 it doesn't works. I already configured the firewall and tried to give this command as suggest in other post:

```
setenforce 0
```

I really need an help.
Thanks

Comment: what is the output of `sestatus | grep mode`

Comment: With "sudo setenforce 1" it give me "Current mode:   enforcing", with "sudo setenforce 0", it give me "Current mode:   permissive".
Either with setenforce 1, either with setenforce 0 doesn't startup and give me always the error described above

Comment: Problem "solved". I started my apache server in SSL mode with port 58247. I still can't understand why I can't use the port 8891.

Comment: That is strange. Can you try few more ports, for example 8890 or 8892?

Comment: They doesn't work...